# Get Value from Override using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to get the value from a virtual property from a inherited class see my code below:

**Base class:**

```
public class TestBaseClass
{
   public virtual int Index { get; }
}
```

**Inherited class:**

```
public class TestInheritedClass : TestBaseClass
{
   public override int Index => 100; // I want to get this value using reflection
}
```

**My Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
   var assemblies = Assembly.LoadFile(args[0]);
   foreach(var type in assembly.ExportedTypes)
   {
      if(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(TestBaseClass))
      {
         foreach(var prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
         {
            var value = prop.GetValue(typeof(int), null); // I expect to return 100 from override Index value
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Did I missed something or did I made this all wrong? I'm trying to get the value `100` from the virtual property. Is there a way to get the value?

Comment: You did miss something. `Index` is an instance property: you need an instance of `TestInheritedClass` in order to access it. You should be passing that instance to `prop.GetValue`, but you're passing `typeof(int)`, i.e. an instance of the `Type` object. It doesn't matter that all instances of `TestInheritedClass` will return the same value: the runtime doesn't know this, and that isn't how the language works

Comment: It's not a static property so you are going to need an instance to make this work. You can use Activator.CreateInstance and use the instance in your GetValue call

Comment: you need to do `var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);` outside foreach loop and then pass `obj` to `prop.GetValue` method as first parameter as `var value = prop.GetValue(obj, null);`

Comment: Thank you so much, I made this through, you guys are very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the value?

Yes, there is a way.
Let's first see what you've done there:

```
prop.GetValue(typeof(int), null)
```

You're using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetValue_System_Object_System_Object___) overload of `PropertyInfo.GetValue`. It expects the instance of the object from which to get the value as first parameter. Instead, you're passing `typeof(int)`. That's not an instance of `TestInheritedClass`.
I will ignore the second parameter here, because we're not talking about an indexer.
You can read about that parameter in the documentation.

Instead you must create an instance of `TestInheritedClass` first:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestInheritedClass));
```

Then use it like this:

```
if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(TestBaseClass))
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    {
       var value = prop.GetValue(instance);
    }
}
```